# how can I extract single column from Array <String> in HIVE???

Tags: json, hive, arrayofstring

I have to extract timeStamp column from this Array  in HIVE?   [{"timeStamp":1506411499989,"status":"BROADCASTED"}]

Comment: Please provide your table ddl and data example

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function and then select the timestamp from the exploded table/view

Answer (score 0):

Use `lateral view`+`explode` and `get_json_object`:

```
select s.*, get_json_object(a.your_json,'$.timeStamp') as timeStamp
  from your_table s
       lateral view outer explode (your_Array) a;
```